# download from s3 bucket ajax php

Tags: php, ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cross-domain

Hey everyone so I'm moving my site over to AWS and s3 using elastic beanstock. I have run into a bit of a problem because my PHP files are stored on a different URL than the s3 bucket is.

For example, my website URL is similar to this http://mysite.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/test2.php, and my s3 bucket URL is similar to this https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/my-media-services/stockUploads/a288f1366c721c3cdcc8d417f866758d/test_184.mp4 as you can see they are different and the HTML download attribute is not supported via cross-origin URLS.

As such is it possible to download the files via ajax so that the user wouldn't have to go to another page and thereby to have a similar experience to the html5 download attribute? If so how would I do this? I'm using AWS PHP SDK

this no longer works because it's on s3 and is cross-origin

`<a href="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/my-media-services/stockUploads/a288f1366c721c3cdcc8d417f866758d/test_184.mp4" download>download</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enable cors on s3 bucket:

1. Select bucket
2. Select permissions tab
3. Select CORS
4. Enable CORS configuration:

   `<CORSConfiguration>
       <CORSRule>
         <AllowedOrigin>http://www.example1.com</AllowedOrigin>
         <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
         <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
         <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
       </CORSRule>
     </CORSConfiguration>`

   [image]

For download the file you need add a metadata to object (mp4):

[image]

Here is working:

```
<a id="download" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/dev-repositorio-imagenes/colocolo/YODA_HD.mp4" download>Download</a>
```

[Read More](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html)

From the server-code it's very important upload the file as:

> content-type:"application/octet-stream"

[How to set content-type PHP SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#putobject)

Hope to help you!

Comment: Ok thats great but how do I actually download the file? What code would I write? This doesnt fix the html 5 download attribute

Comment: please share server-side code for that i can help you

Comment: no matter what I do it acts as a link <a href="mys3link" download>download</a>

Comment: you said: _I'm using AWS PHP SDK_ .- please share your code for i know if can help.

Comment: heres my code and the real link `<a href="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/prismview-media-services/bannerStockUpload/a288f1366c721c3cdcc8d417f866758d/YODA_HD.mp4" download class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Download</a>` that is my real link and here is my cors `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>0</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>`

Comment: I added content-disposition and attachment in the meta data but to no avail do I need to change my link I notice that your link does not contain .us-east-2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182438/discussion-between-ene-salinas-and-codernoob8).